# Unable to hide panel in extjs

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

I have 2 grids and 1 panel in a page.
Initially the grids are visible and the panel is hidden. On click of a button I enable the panel and hide the 2 grids using:

```
firstGrid.hide();
secondGrid.hide();
firstPanel.show();
```

After saving records on the panel, I want to hide the panel and enable the grids, which I tried using this:

```
firstGrid.show();
secondGrid.show();
alert(firstPanel); //<-- firstPanel is not defined (error console)
firstPanel.hide();
```

As a result the all the 3 (2 grids and 1 panel) are visible which is not desired. I want to hide the panel.
Can anyone please educate me by pointing out the mistake?

**Panel Layout:**

```
var firstPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: '<center>First Panel</center>',
    margin:'20 0 0 0',
    autoHeight: true,
    width:780,
    standardSubmit:false,
store: storeName,
    hidden:true,
 frame: true,
    layout: {
    type: 'table',
        columns: 4
}, defaults: {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle: 'background-color:#dfe8f5;'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype:'textfield',width:120,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 0',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'First Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap1',width:199, height:26,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '1 0 1 0',  dataIndex: 'firstVar',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; text-align: center;border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:100,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 20',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Second Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap2',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',readOnly:true,  dataIndex: 'secondVar',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; text-align: center;border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:100,height:31,colspan:1,margin: '0 0 0 0',readOnly:true,
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Third Field'
    },{
        xtype: 'datefield', id : 'usap3', anchor: '100%', name: 'stockAsOn', format: 'd/m/Y', width: 199, altFormats: 'd-M-y',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;', height: 26
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:100,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 20',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Fourth Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap4',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:100,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 0',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Fifth Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap5',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:100,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 20',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Sixth Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap6',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:100,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 0',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Seventh Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap7',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:151,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 20',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Eigth Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap8',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:151,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 0',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Ninth Field'
    },{
        xtype:'textfield',id:'usap9',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:151,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 20',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'tenth Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap10',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',width:151,height:31,colspan:1,readOnly:true,margin: '0 0 0 0',
            fieldStyle: 'background-color: #dfe8f5; background-image: none; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #505050;',
            value:'Eleventh Field'
    },{
            xtype:'textfield',id:'usap11',width:199,height:26,colspan:1,margin: '1 0 1 0',
            fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
    },{
        html:'',
        border:false
 }],
    buttons: [{
        xtype: 'checkbox', id:'usapCheck', boxLabel: 'I Accept', allowBlank: false, margin: '1 1 4 230'
 },{
        buttonAlign: 'right',margin:'0 0 0 3.6',text: 'Save',width: '30',iconCls: 'save',
        handler: function() {
            if(Ext.getCmp('usapCheck').getValue()){
                saveMethod();

            }else{
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Please accept before saving the form');
            }
        }
    },{
            buttonAlign: 'right',margin:'1 1 0 3.6',text: 'Clear',width: '30',iconCls: 'clear',
        handler: function() {
            clearfirstPanel();
        }
    },{
        buttonAlign: 'right',margin:'1 1 1 1.6',text: 'Back',width: '30',iconCls: 'back',
        handler: function() {
            firstGrid.show();
            secondGrid.show();
            firstPanel.hide(); //this part is working fine. Here it gets hidden
        }
    }],
    renderTo: 'panelDiv'
});
 function saveMethod(){.....
---AjaxCall----
    if(jsonTxt.sucFlg==1){
         Ext.MessageBox.alert('Record Saved Successfully');
        firstGrid.show();
        secondGrid.show();
        firstPanel.hide();
    }.....
 }
```

Comment: Please post your layout code

Comment: @DarinKolev The layout of the whole page is quite huge. So I have just posted the panel part and the method to hide it.

Comment: More important is the layout of the parent container where all the grids and the panel are included. The layout of the panel is not important

Comment: @DarinKolev Parent container is just a jsp. All the grids are placed in either `Ext.onReady(function(){});` and the panel is inside the call of a function on button click from firstGrid. Or Shall I paste the whole js page code? 1200 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding id : 'firstPanel' to your panel and then doing `Ext.getCmp('firstPanel').hide();` on the save Method.

Comment: getCmp() is never to be recommended

Comment: With the given information, what would be the ideal approach ? I'm fairly new to Extjs myself so i'm always willing to learn some more

Comment: @PedroReis you can use the Ext.ComponentQuery.query or scope.down or scope.up to refer the component istead of adding an id and refering it using  Ext.getCmp.

Comment: I thought of component up / down for this, but i think we'd need more info on the layout.. Or possibly a controller reference depending on where all this is happening. Never userd ComponentQuery i think.. i'll look into it. Ty